# Call Button não funciona

Tags: android

Olá, apos tentar todos os tutoriais e mais algum decidi que não consigo resolver mesmo o problema, quero criar um botão que redirecione para uma chamada para um determinado numero acontece é que o botão não faz nada, nem erro, nem aviso,...

Este é o Java:

```
    public class APizzaria extends Fragment {

    private Button button;
    View inflatedView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizzaria_1, container,false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        button = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                String number = "23454568678";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizzaria_1, container, false);

        return android;
    }
}
```

Este é o layout:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView06"
        android:text="@string/Telefone" />
```

E adicionei as permissões no Manifest, podem me ajudar a descobrir o porque de não estar a funcionar?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendo o porquê desta linha:
`this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizzaria_1, container,false);`.

Apaga-a e move a linha:
`View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizzaria_1, container, false);`
para esse lugar.

Altera a linha:
`button = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.button);`
para
`button = (Button) android.findViewById(R.id.button);`

Julgo que o problema está em que o `onClick` é atribuído ao botão da `View` da variável *inflatedView* mas o que é retornado pelo método é a variável *android*.

O código deverá ficar assim:

```
public class APizzaria extends Fragment {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pizzaria_1, container, false);

        button = (Button) android.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                String number = "23454568678";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return android;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema.